# windows PC configuration: force logout/ kill existing sessions on restart

Tags: windows, powershell

As part of our PC Build ,configuration and deployment process, we use Window Deployment toolkit and WCD (windows configuration designer) to setup 4 users with different access. Some users are in kiosk mode.

We see that when a user is logged in and we perform a hard shutdown (pull power cable), then when we start the computer again, the user session is still active, and we are unable to logout the user , unless we have the password.

Is there a way to force on windows start that any existing sessions are closed and that we have the default login screen, where any user can login? For security considerations we prefer to kill existing sessions fo rthe hard shutdown case.

Ideally we would like to configure this with powershell or the WCD tool.

Comment: `the user session is still active`.  There needs to be more information. How is this being confirmed?

Comment: when we restart, we have a screen with only the current user being displayed and being prompted for passwords.  We cannot select other users,  without first logging this user out.  This is an issue because if for whatever reason the user is no longer there, we are blocked.

Comment: I have never heard of this. Not being able to logon without logging off another user. It should always be possible to logon, even if it means logging off the existing session. Although that is rarely required, due to most organizations that have workstations accessed by multiple accounts leave Fast User Switching enabled.

Comment: Do you have local group policy settings set on the machine? Delete the `"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"` and `"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy"` folders, then reboot and see if problem exists. I actually can think of a configuration where this is possible Windows 10 and Windows 11. If you are setting policies though, you should test to narrow down what's needed for the configuration to work as expected. Process of elimination, trial and error, and multiple reboot may be required sometimes. I assume you are not getting domain group policies doing this but those could do it too.

Comment: after some testing,  er found solution using hint from @Pimp Juice IT, I posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint from @Pimp Juice IT was very helpful

The setting is indeed in Group policies under Windows Components=>Windows Logon Options=>

Sign-in last interactive user automatically after a system-initiated restart.  Setting the state of that policy to Disabled solves the problem.

Comment: I believe that option does not work via domain joined machines and domain credentials that are logged on so these must be local group policy options and local accounts then, correct? Good job!!

Comment: yes indeed I am working in a local accounts scenario, did not test on domain joined machines.